# Trying to access the console from the dashboard returns: "console is currently unavailable."

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

I have openstack-dashboard installed from openstack-base in a MAAS environment and it seems to be working for almost everything.  I can view and change networks/routers/ports and start an instance.  I have an instance with a floating IP that I can ping and telnet to the ssh port.  ssh ubuntu@floatingip connects and then times out.

Trying to access the console from the dashboard returns: console is currently unavailable. Please try again later.

When I do "juju ssh x" to the nova-compute node where my instance is running, a virst list returns:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 5     instance-00000002              running
```

but `virsh console 5` returns:

```
Connected to domain instance-00000002
Escape character is ^]
error: internal error: character device <null> is not using a PTY
```

I have verified that nova-authconsole is up and running.

When I look at `/var/lib/instances/{instance}/console.log` it shows a full console log and everything from the boot up looks correct.  nova-cloud-controller has console-access-protocl set to novnc.  console-proxy-ip is set to local.

I suspect that all three methods of trying to access the instance are caused by a single failure, but don't know where else to look for it.

Any ideas of how to track this one down?

Comment: If you ssh into the compute node (juju ssh nova-compute/X), what do you get when running "ps aux | grep vnc"?, it should match the qemu process for your VM, if you get an empty output then that means qemu didn't launch the VM with vnc enabled and you need to run "nova stop ID" and "nova start ID" ("nova reboot" won't work as it won't stop/start the qemu process with the new command line arguments)

Comment: Yes, qemu is running with "-vnc 0.0.0:0".

Comment: I am not sure what I did.  vnc /novnc started working while I was playing with different MTU sizes.  The MTU settings are all back to normal, but the console access continues to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable console access in the nova-cloud-controller charm? The configuration key is called `console-access-protocol`:

```
Protocol to use when accessing virtual machine console. Supported types
are None, spice, xvpvnc, novnc and vnc (for both xvpvnc and novnc)
```

Comment: yes, I have it set to novnc.  I suspect that it may have something to do with mtu.  I saw this in another post, http://askubuntu.com/questions/486151/can-ping-but-cannot-ssh-to-openstack-vm-instance?rq=1.  I started playing with values and the console started working along with inbound networking, but not outbound network access.  Then everything went to hell in a handbasket and I am trying to sort through which settings to use and which to discard.  I am now back to console access without any network access.

Comment: Also note that it only applies to instances started after the config change.